# Include space within telephone number 077 12345678

Tags: regex, typescript

I've been tasked to allow our telephone number field to include a space.

Here is the current regex. Written in a .ts file

```
  {
    name: 'telephoneNumber',
    type: 'text',
    label: 'Phone number',
    value: '',
    validators: [
      {
        type: Validators.required,
        text: 'Phone number is required.',
      },
      {
        type: Validators.pattern(
          new RegExp(
            '^((\\(?0\\d{4}\\)?\\s?\\d{3}\\s?\\d{3})|(\\(?0\\d{3}\\)?\\s?\\d{3}\\s?\\d{4})|(\\(?0\\d{2}\\)?\\s?\\d{4}\\s?\\d{4}))|(\\(\\d{2,4}\\)?\\s?\\d{10,11})|(\\+\\d{2,4}\\)?\\s?\\d{10,11})(\\s?\\#(\\d{4}|\\d{3}))?$',
          ),
        ),
        text: 'Please enter a valid 11-digit phone number.',
      },
      {
        type: Validators.maxLength(11),
        text: 'Please enter a valid 11-digit phone number.',
      },
    ],
    tooltip:
      'This is the best number for us to contact you, typically a mobile. Don’t worry, we will only contact you if you have asked us to.',
  },
```

I am able to get around this by changing the maxLength to allow 12 characters but feel this isn't the right way to do it.

I don't have much experience with Regex so any information or suggestions on how to approach this would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put in an optional space in your regex where you want to allow spaces. That is:  `[ ]?` (note the space between brackets).

Answer (score 1):

I would simply remove all spaces using a simple \s regex replace before validating the number length.

If you need to do it in the expression though, here is a simple expression that allows for any 11 digit phone number starting with a zero and any amount of spaces between the digits.

```
0(?:\d\s*){10}
```

https://regex101.com/r/G3mUKp/1